# php unable to open file when open and write into file

Tags: php

i try to read a text file line by line and if any line contain "/" then i need to write them into separate file.
example line

```
CA,T2B,Calgary (Forest Lawn / Dover / Erin Woods),Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
```

i need to write this as 4 lines, like

```
CA,T2B,Calgary,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
CA,T2B, Forest Lawn ,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
CA,T2B, Dover,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
CA,T2B, Erin Woods,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
```

what i've tried so far is

```
$file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

while (!feof($file)) {
  $my_string = fgets($file);
  $special_chars = array("/");
  if (array_intersect(str_split($my_string), $special_chars)) {
    echo fgets($file) . "<br />";
    $myfile = fopen("fileWithFL.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, fgets($file));
    fclose($myfile);
  }else{
    echo fgets($file) . "<br />";
    $myfile = fopen("fileWithoutFL.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, fgets($file));
    fclose($myfile);
  }
}

fclose($file);
```

[[image: file i try to read][1]]
file i get from "[CA.zip](http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/)"

how can i do this?
thank you!

Comment: i dont understand what you want to write? can you add more details

Comment: if file contain "/" included line like `CA,T2B,Calgary (Forest Lawn / Dover / Erin Woods),Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6` i need to write that line as `CA,T2B,Calgary,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
CA,T2B, Forest Lawn ,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
CA,T2B, Dover,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
CA,T2B, Erin Woods,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
` in new file

Comment: simply i need to them as separate lines(separate similar town names)

Comment: ahh i get it now

Comment: i appreciate any help.

Comment: it this every line end with ) if the string contains / ?

Comment: yes every line end with ) if the string contains /

Comment: added answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're repeatedly opening and closing `fileWithFL.txt` and `fileWithoutFL.txt`, which is inefficient. Better to just open them once before you loop through the input file.

You're also using `fgets()`, which makes it difficult to parse the input file. Since the input file seems to be in CSV format, you should use `fgetcsv()`.

As for detecting rows that contain multiple cities, I'm looking for the presence of `/`, splitting on `(` or `/`), removing any trailing `)`, and trimming the resulting name. That should give you all the cities in a neat array.

```
$file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

$file_with_fl = fopen("fileWithFL.txt", "w+");
$file_without_fl = fopen("fileWithoutFL.txt", "w+");

while ($a = fgetcsv($file)) {
    if ( FALSE == strpos( $a[2], '/' ) ) {
        fputcsv( $file_without_fl, $a );
    } else {
        $cities = preg_split( '/[\(\/]/', $a[2] ); // Split on '(' and '/'
        foreach ( $cities as $city ) {
            $city = trim(preg_replace('/\)/', '', $city)); // Remove trailing ')' and trim leading and trailing spaces
            $a[2] = $city;
            fputcsv( $file_with_fl, $a );
        }
    }
}
```

Checking for failure of `fopen()` and `fputcsv()` left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: why it's printing with double quotes like `CA,T2B,"Erin Woods",Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
`?

Comment: That's how `fputcsv()` works: it quotes entries with spaces, per CSV standards. If you don't like that, change it to `fwrite($file_with_fl, join(',', $a))`. (You'll obviously have to make that change to both calls to `fputcsv()`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file_put_contents(file, string, FILE_APPEND)` to add a line to the end of a file.
The rest is just processing the **Calgary (Forest Lawn / Dover / Erin Woods)** part of your string.

```
$string = 'CA,T2B,Calgary (Forest Lawn / Dover / Erin Woods),Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6';

//test if string needs processing
//if not, write straight to new file
if(strpos($string,'/') === false){
    file_put_contents("fileWithoutFL.txt" , $string , FILE_APPEND);
    }

//process
else{
     //get all the parts split by comma
     //$parts[2] is the one you need processing
   $parts = explode(',',$string);

     //clean up $part[2], replacing ( , ) with *
     //then split on the *
   $com=explode('*',str_replace(['(','/',')'],'*',$parts[2]));

     //loop $com, creating new arrays by replacing $part[2] in the original array
   foreach($com as $val){
      if($val == '')continue;
        //replace $part[2] cleaning up spaces
      $parts[2] = trim($val);
        //make a new line
      $write = implode(',',$parts);
        //write to the new file
      file_put_contents("fileWithoutFL.txt" , $write , FILE_APPEND);
      }
   }
```

Now you can read every line of the original file and output to the new file. (Tip: use [`SplFileObject`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php))

```
$file = new SplFileObject("fileWithFL.txt");
while (!$file->eof()) {
   $string = $file->fgets();
   // ... process here with previous code
  
 }
$file = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer but its works

```
  $line = file_get_contents("test.txt");
  $body = "";

  if(false !== strpos($line,"/")) {
    $split = preg_split("/[()]+/", $line,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $contains = explode("/",$split[1]);
    $last = explode(",",$split[0]);
    $lastvalue = end($last);
    $search = array_search($lastvalue,$last);
    unset($last[$search]);
    $merge = implode(", ", $last);
    $body .= $merge . $split[2] . " ";

    foreach($contains as $contain) {
      $body .= $split[0] . "," . $contain . $split[2] . " ";
    }

    if(file_put_contents("fileWithFL.txt",$body) !== false) {
      echo $body;
    } else {
      echo "failed";
    }

  } else {

    if(file_put_contents("fileWithoutFL.txt",$line) !== false) {
      echo $line;
    } else {
      echo "failed";
    }

  }
```

Output :

```
 CA, T2B,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6 CA,T2B,Calgary ,Forest Lawn ,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6 CA,T2B,Calgary , Dover ,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6 CA,T2B,Calgary , Erin Woods,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
```

Comment: Use `trim()` to get rid of the unwanted spaces around the cities.

Comment: thank you very much! but output is little bit different than i except.

Comment: what is different? can you explain?

Comment: it should be like `CA,T2B,Calgary,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
CA,T2B, Forest Lawn ,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
CA,T2B, Dover,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
CA,T2B, Erin Woods,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6`  the main name`Calgary` should be in one line

Comment: `CA,T2B,Calgary,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
CA,T2B, Forest Lawn ,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
CA,T2B, Dover,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
CA,T2B, Erin Woods,Alberta,AB,Calgary,,,,51.0209,-113.981,6
`  need new line for each similer name + main name bro

Comment: actually you can test adding space and line in the code, in body variable